# Как создать класс реализующий Parcelable, если в его конструктор в качестве входного параметра передается объект?

Tags: java, android

В примерах, посвященных созданию классов реализующих интерфейс **Parcelable** всегда в качестве аргументов конструктора выступают либо переменные примитивных типов, либо объекты класса **String**.

Вопрос как передать в конструкторе класса, реализующего интерфейс **Parcelable** объект пользовательского класса? Например,

```
public class DocumentInfo implements Parcelable {
    private Doc document;

    public DocumentInfo(Doc document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    public DocumentInfo(Parcel in) {
        //Как прочитать объект document из in?
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //Как записать в dest объект document?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

По контракту вы должны описать переменную **CREATOR** с типом **Parcelable.Creator**, которая и позволяет создать объект вашего типа.

**Parcelable** нужен для того, что бы вы могли **завернуть** свой объект в **Parcel** и в другом месте в вашем коде **достать** его из **Parcel**. Это похоже на сериализацию/десериализацию объекта, тут в качестве потока выступает **Parcel**.

То есть вы должны все поля из **Doc** записать в **Parcel** и потом прочитать их из него. Так как вы не предоставили класс **Doc**, то в качестве примера, я предположил, что в нем есть поле типа **int** с getter/setter.

```
public class DocumentInfo implements Parcelable {
    Private Doc document;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(document.getSomeInt());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<DocumentInfo> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<DocumentInfo>() {
        public DocumentInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new DocumentInfo(in);
        }

        public DocumentInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new DocumentInfo[size];
        }
    };

    private DocumentInfo(Parcel in) {
        document = new Doc();
        document.setSomeInt(in.readInt());
    }

    public DocumentInfo(Doc doc) {
        document = doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Конструктор DocumentInfo должен получить объект класса Doc в качестве аргумента и присвоить его атрибуту класса document. Я не понимаю причем здесь :   document = new Doc();
        document.setSomeInt(in.readInt());

Comment: Поучить откуда? Какой из классов должен реализовывать **Parcelable** - **DocumentInfo** или **Doc**?

Comment: DocumentInfo реализует Parcelable, а Doc это интерфейс, имеющий один метод. Интерфейс Doc реализуется классом, описанным в MainActivity, в onCreate которой создается объект DocumentInfo, который и должен передаваться в сервис. Для этого он должен реализовать Parcelable. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.))

Comment: вы знакомы с сериализацией? **Doc** можно преобразовать в массив байт и восстановить из массива байт?

Comment: Не знаком честно говоря.

Comment: а на второй вопрос ответите? добавьте в вопрос интерфейс **Doc** и его реализацию.

Comment: Ну эти понятия я вообще для примера придумал. Вот статья http://interosite.ru/articles/bluetooth-for-android . Моя задача вынести ServerThread в сервис. Т.к. в конструкторе сервиса нельзя передавать объекты, я решил действовать через  Parcelable. Может быть опираясь на пример по ссылке Вы подскажете как  ServerThread может реализовать  Parcelable. Если Вы обратите внимание, там в конструкторе передается объект CommunicatorService communicatorService.

Comment: статье 3 года. за это время все поменялось. и **Parcelable** в статье не используется.

Comment: В статье написано: ServerThread принимает входящие соединения и читает данные из полученного сокета. Поток ServerThread запущен все время, пока MainActivity находится в активном состоянии (между вызовами onResume и onPause). Возможно, в вашем приложении вы захотите вынести ServerThread в сервис, так чтобы его работа не зависела от состояния пользовательского интерфейса (активности). Вот я и захотел вынести ServerThread в сервис. Но чтобы передать объект класса в сервис, он должен реализовывать интерфейс Parcelable, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: я добавил пояснения в ответ

Comment: Спасибо, решения пока нет, но некоторые моменты прояснились.

Comment: если вы добавите в вопрос, то что я прошу, то я попробую улучшить ответ.

Comment: Михаил, ваши пояснения навели на мысль, что мой подход был изначально не правильный. Создал новый вопрос, в котором описал первоначальную проблему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685277/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-creator-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-parcelable