# Ошибки при реализации поля CREATOR интерфейса Parcelable

Tags: java, android

Если я реализую интерфейс Parcelable в классе, объявленном в MainActivity, у меня возникают проблемы с полем CREATOR.

```
public static final Creator<CommunicatorServiceImpl> CREATOR = new Creator<CommunicatorServiceImpl>() {
    @Override
    public CommunicatorServiceImpl createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CommunicatorServiceImpl(in);
    }

    @Override
    public CommunicatorServiceImpl[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CommunicatorServiceImpl[size];
    }
};
```

1.Ошибка "Inner class cannot have static declaration"

2.В этом месте

```
return new CommunicatorServiceImpl(in);
```

ругается "MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from a static context".

Мне нужно реализовать интерфейс Parcelable в этом классе, потому что мне нужно передать объект этого класса в службу. Как я могу решить эти проблемы?

Код MainActivity и класса CommunicatorServiceImpl здесь: http://www.note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/6e53f3deeeb039227c83eab5746f341a?page=1

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что `Parcelable` предназначен для сериализации? С помощью него можно передавать только простые data-классы. Вы не сможете передать объект целиком, и тем более его состояние или вложенные в него объекты.

Comment: А как передать объект в сервис? Через конструктор же тоже нельзя.